# The documents were not zipped correctly

Tags: delphi

I'm making a class to create a docx document, directly from code.
An example is shown in the code below. Using this code, MS WORD opens the document, but libreoffice, openoffice show that the document is damaged.

However, if I rename the docx document to zip type, using Windows explorer, and unpack the document, then using the "Send to compressed (zipped) folder" option and change the document type to docx, all mentioned text editors open the document. Where am I wrong?

```
unit uWordX;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Xml.xmldom, Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.XmlDoc;

    type
      TWordxClass = class
      private
        FOwner    : TComponent;
        procedure CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument: TXmlDocument);
        function SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument: TXmlDocument): TStream;
        function AddAttributes(RootAttribute: IXMLNode; NodeName: string; attrNames: Array of string; attrValues: array of string): IXMLNode;

    function CreateRelsRels: TStream;
    function CreateRelsDocumentXMLRels: TStream;
    function CreateContentTypes: TStream;

    function CreateSimpleDoc: TStream;
  public
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;

    procedure CreateFile(AFileName: string);
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Zip;

{ TWordxClass }

function TWordxClass.AddAttributes(RootAttribute: IXMLNode; NodeName: string;
  attrNames, attrValues: array of string): IXMLNode;
begin
  Result  := RootAttribute.AddChild(NodeName);
  for var idx := Low(attrValues) to High(attrValues) do
    Result.Attributes[attrNames[idx]] := attrValues[idx];
end;

constructor TWordxClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FOwner    := AOwner;
end;

function TWordxClass.CreateContentTypes: TStream;
begin
  var XmlDocument := TXmlDocument.Create(FOwner);
  try
    CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument);
    // Root Node
    var Root := XmlDocument.addChild('Types',
      'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types');
    var Def := AddAttributes(Root, 'Default', ['Extension', 'ContentType'],
                ['rels', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml']);
    Def     := AddAttributes(Root, 'Default', ['Extension', 'ContentType'],
                ['xml', 'application/xml']);
    var Ovr := AddAttributes(Root, 'Override',
                ['PartName', 'ContentType'],
                ['/word/document.xml', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml']);

    Result := SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument);
  finally
    XmlDocument.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TWordxClass.CreateFile(AFileName: string);
begin
  var FZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    FZipFile.Open(AFileName, TZipMode.zmWrite);
    var CntType := CreateContentTypes();
    try

      FZipFile.Add(CntType, '[Content_Types].xml');
    finally
      CntType.Free;
    end;

    var RelsStream := CreateRelsRels();
    try

      FZipFile.Add(RelsStream, '_rels\.rels');
    finally
      RelsStream.Free;
    end;

    var RelsDocumentXMLRels := CreateRelsDocumentXMLRels();
    try
      FZipFile.Add(RelsDocumentXMLRels, 'word/_rels/document.xml.rels');
    finally
      RelsDocumentXMLRels.Free;
    end;

    var Document := CreateSimpleDoc();
    try
      FZipFile.Add(Document, 'word/document.xml');
    finally
      Document.Free;
    end;
    FZipFile.Close;
  finally
    FZipFile.Free;
  end;
end;

function TWordxClass.CreateRelsDocumentXMLRels: TStream;
begin
  var XmlDocument := TXmlDocument.Create(FOwner);
  try
    CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument);
    // Root Node
    var Root := XmlDocument.addChild('Relationships',
      'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships');
    Result := SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument);
  finally
    XmlDocument.Free;
  end;
end;

function TWordxClass.CreateRelsRels: TStream;
begin
  var XmlDocument := TXmlDocument.Create(FOwner);
  try
    CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument);
    // Root Node
    var Root := XmlDocument.addChild('Relationships',
      'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships');
    // Relationship Definition
    var Rel := Root.addChild('Relationship');
    Rel.Attributes['Id'] := 'rId1';
    Rel.Attributes['Type'] :=
      'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument';
    Rel.Attributes['Target'] := 'word/document.xml';
    Result := SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument);
  finally
    XmlDocument.Free;
  end;
end;

function TWordxClass.CreateSimpleDoc: TStream;
begin
  var XmlDocument := TXmlDocument.Create(FOwner);
  try
    CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument);
    // Root Node
    var Doc := XmlDocument.AddChild('w:document');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wpc', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('mc', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('o', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('r', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('m', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('v', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wp14', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wp', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('w10', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('w', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('w14', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wpg', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wpi', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wne', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml');
    Doc.DeclareNamespace('wps', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape');
    Doc.Attributes['mc:Ignorable']  := 'w14 wp14';

    var Body  := Doc.AddChild('w:body');
    var Paragraf  := AddAttributes(Body, 'w:p', ['w:rsidR', 'w:rsidRDefault'], ['005F670F', '005F79F5']);
    var Text  := Paragraf.AddChild('w:r').AddChild('w:t');
    Text.NodeValue    := 'Tekst';


    var bookmarkStart := AddAttributes(Paragraf, 'w:bookmarkStart', ['w:id', 'w:name'], ['0', '_GoBack']);
    var bookmarkEnd := AddAttributes(Paragraf, 'w:bookmarkEnd', ['w:id'], ['0']);

    var SectPtr := AddAttributes(Body, 'w:sectPr', ['w:rsidR'], ['005F670F']);
    var PageSize  := AddAttributes(SectPtr, 'w:pgSz', ['w:w', 'w:h'], ['12240', '15840']);
    var PageMargine := AddAttributes(SectPtr, 'w:pgMar', ['w:top', 'w:right', 'w:bottom', 'w:left', 'w:header', 'w:footer', 'w:gutter'],
                                                         ['1440', '1440', '1440', '1440', '720', '720', '0']);
    var Cols    := AddAttributes(SectPtr, 'w:cols', ['w:space'], ['720']);
    var DocGrid := AddAttributes(SectPtr, 'w:docGrid', ['w:linePitch'], ['360']);

    Result := SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument);
  finally
    XmlDocument.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TWordxClass.CreateXmlHeader(XmlDocument: TXmlDocument);
begin
  XmlDocument.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  XmlDocument.Active := True;
  XmlDocument.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  XmlDocument.Version := '1.0';
  XmlDocument.StandAlone := 'yes';
end;

function TWordxClass.SaveXmlDocToStream(XmlDocument: TXmlDocument): TStream;
begin
  Result  := TMemoryStream.Create;
  XmlDocument.SaveToStream(Result);
  Result.Seek(0, soBeginning);
end;

end.
```

Documents are uploaded on address: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1GPfLjMYPwaI-E5ZEEwxlORy_b_PZI1cJ

Document TestSimple.docx was generated by the code, and [Content_Types].docx is rezipped document. MSWord and Mac's TextEdit open TestSimple.docx, and applications OpenOffice and LibreOffice can't open it. After unzipping the original document, recompressing and renaming to docx extension using Windows Explorer, all mentioned applications open the new document.

Thanks in advance,

Bojan

Comment: Where do you set the ZIP compression method? Oh, nowhere. If you don't care for details then don't be surprised at different outcomes. Why not comparing how both your and the rezipped file to see the differences?

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately you are not right that the zip compression method is not set. It is by default "deflate". procedure Add(Data: TStream; const ArchiveFileName: string; Compression: TZipCompression = zcDeflate;
      AExternalAttributes: TFileAttributes = []); overload;

Comment: I opened both with 7zip and I don't see the difference. I wouldn't ask if I didn't do it. 2 days I don't notice a difference.

Comment: Again, MS Word opens a file generated this way, but OpenOffice and LibreOffice do not open it.

Comment: I checked, TextEdit on Mac, also opens the generated file by code.

Comment: Link both ZIP files (your created one, the repacked one by your OS or whatever you use for that). Of course you have to look at their structure, not just "use" them in any ZIP software which automatically lists (and sorts) filename entries. When editing your Q consider adding the tags ZIP and DOCX to it. Also you're able to edit comments - no need to spam 4 in a row as if this is a chat.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GPfLjMYPwaI-E5ZEEwxlORy_b_PZI1cJ?usp=sharing            is link to the files. TestSamples.docx is file generated by code, [Content_Types].docx are same xml files zipped by WE. (About edit, it is possible only within 5 minutes)

Comment: Please edit your **question** to include relevant details and links. The former file has the UTF-8 flag set, as can be seen in the 7-Zip FM (column "Characteristics") - the latter doesn't. Consider setting `TZipFile.UTF8Support` to `FALSE`.

Comment: Sorry I was on the business trip 2 days and wasn't able to edit question. Setting TZipFile.UTF8Support to FALSE isn't solution. I checked it this morning and behaviour is same.